# UIAlert in Swift that automatically disappears?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I have the following code:

```
    /// Creates Alerts on screen for user.
func notifyUser(title: String, message: String) -> Void
{
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title,
        message: message,
        preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK",
        style: .Cancel, handler: nil)

    alert.addAction(cancelAction)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController!.presentViewController(alert, animated: true,
        completion: nil)
}
```

Which shows the following Alert:

[image]

I would prefer the Alert to appear for maybe 1-2 seconds and auto dismiss without having to click ok or dismiss. Is this possible?

Comment: You can use an NSTimer to dismiss the alert controller

Comment: Changing the UX of how the UIAlert works is maybe not the best approach, consider a custom view?

Answer (score 4):

Yes it's completely possible, I think the @Duncan C approach will work very well and it's self explanatory, so I going to explain you in code the @Duncan approach and another approach is using delays with the **Grand Central Dispatch**(GCD).

> **First Approach: Using the `NSTimer` class**

```
// set the UIAlerController property
var alert: UIAlertController!

func notifyUser(title: String, message: String, timeToDissapear: Int) -> Void
{
    alert = UIAlertController(title: title,
        message: message,
        preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK",
        style: .Cancel, handler: nil)

    alert.addAction(cancelAction)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController!.presentViewController(alert, animated: true,
        completion: nil)

    // setting the NSTimer to close the alert after timeToDissapear seconds.
    _ = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(Double(timeToDissapear), target: self, selector: Selector("dismissAlert"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}
```

> **Second Approach: Using GCD**

```
// set the UIAlerController property
var alert: UIAlertController! 

func notifyUser(title: String, message: String, timeToDissapear: Int) -> Void
{
    alert = UIAlertController(title: title,
        message: message,
        preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK",
        style: .Cancel, handler: nil)

    alert.addAction(cancelAction)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController!.presentViewController(alert, animated: true,
        completion: nil)

    // Delay the dismissal by timeToDissapear seconds
    let delay = Double(timeToDissapear) * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
    let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
    dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) { [weak self] in
        self!.alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

And then you can call it in anywhere you want like in the following way :

```
self.notifyUser("Hello", message: "World", timeToDissapear: 3)
```

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 2):

Here Is the code for Swift 4 Please Refer...Thank you

```
  let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: "Record Updated Successfully", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { action in
        switch action.style{
        case .default:
            print("default")

        case .cancel:
            print("cancel")

        case .destructive:
            print("destructive")

        }}))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {

        alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Fansad. This is so simple.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. A `UIAlertController` is a special type of `UIViewController`. You're displaying it using `presentViewController:animated:completion:`. Just save a pointer to the `UIAlertController` into an instance variable, start a timer, and when the timer fires, call `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`. You might want to get rid of the OK button action in that case, and if you leave the OK button you'll need to test and make sure your code works if you click OK before the timer fires.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5.0, target: self, selector: "dismissAlert", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


func dismissAlert()
{
     // Dismiss the alert from here
     alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)

}
```

I tried it and this worked fine. You can set the timer inside

> scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval

where the current time is set to 5.0 seconds

Answer (score 0):

```
func alert2 (_ dictKey: String){
    if self.presentedViewController == nil {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil,     message: dictKey, preferredStyle: .alert )
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "START AGAIN", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {(action:UIAlertAction!) in self.returnToStart()}))
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "REQUEST PIN", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:{(action:UIAlertAction!) in self.pinCreate()
        self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)//This dismisses the alert
        }))
        self.present(alertController, animated: true,completion: nil)
    }

}
```

This proved to be a simple solution

Answer (score 0):

```
 func notifyUser(message: String) -> Void {
  let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
  present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
  DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) { [unowned self] in
   self.dismiss(animated: true)
  }
 }
```

To use:

```
  notifyUser(message: "Image Saved")
```