# UIAlert in Swift that automatically disappears after logout

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I'm trying to present an alert after user logs out. I want this to disappear after, let's say, 3 seconds. I've followed some solution on [UIAlert in Swift that automatically disappears?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35094360/uialert-in-swift-that-automatically-disappears)

Following is my code. The problem I'm facing is that after user logs out the I'm navigating away to another view (Home VC) hence I'm getting error:

**dismissAlert]: unrecognized selector sent to instance**

How do I make it work in this scenario?

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Logged out", preferredStyle: .alert)

let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

alert.addAction(cancelAction)

UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController!.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

_ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: Double(3), target: self, selector: Selector(("dismissAlert")), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using [`scheduledTimer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/2091889-scheduledtimer) with block which is called after time interval? I think this solution is Swift-ier then using selector

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Logged out", preferredStyle: .alert)
...
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3, repeats: false) { _ in
    alert.dismiss(animated: true)
    // code from dismissAlert if it is necessary
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to declare your method like that

```
_ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: Double(3), target: self, selector: #selector(dismissAlert), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

@objc func dismissAlert() {
    // your works
}
```

Comment: Tx I got it working finally. There is extra ) in #selector(dismissAlert)) in your answer. Can you please fix it?